# Eisenstein part of the theta series of lattices in same genus

Tags: modular-forms

In Lynne Walling's paper "A Remark on Differences of Theta Series" (see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X84710651), it is proved that the difference of theta series attached to lattices in the same genus is a cusp form.

My question is:
Given a genus symbol (of a lattice which is in general not of square free level),
can one explicitly compute the Eisenstein part of the theta series attached to lattices in the same genus?

Comment: Siegel-Weil formula gives a general assertion that "in principle" should include such a thing, but probably requires a bit of work to "unpack" into more immediate combinatorial terms...

Comment: @paulgarrett Are there any explicit formula for the first 10 coefficients of the Eisenstein series? (I work on spherical designs, and don't have much background on modular forms.)